# How can I clear individual cookies on firefox?

Tags: firefox-for-android, cookies

For a specific website, I clicked on "Show desktop version" link. Unfortunately the desktop version is so broken I cannot use it even to click on "Mobile version" link. Because the website remembers the setting using cookies, I need to clear that specific cookie to get mobile version of the website back.

When I use "Guest mode" in Firefox, the website works which confirms my hypothesis that cookie causes my problems. Therefore the question: How to delete one specific cookie in firefox on android? I tried installing some plugins, but all I got was "Installation failed" toast message on screen.

Comment: Could you mention the link of that website?

Comment: Why is it relevant? Anyway, it's Czech HTML e-mail client, so you'd need to register to see anything.

Comment: Does unchecking "Request Desktop Site" not help in this case? Also, is the device rooted?

Comment: The device is not rooted and the "Request Desktop Site" was never checked, so it's impossible to uncheck it.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox for Android stores Cookies  in `/data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/files/mozilla/{YOUR_PROFILE}/cookies.sqlite`.

You can't peek into Firefox's data directory without having elevated privileges than what is granted to a normal user, call it superuser access. If you have root access then simply pull that file into PC and open it in an SQLite viewer. Search the Cookies using domain name and purge the ones bothering you. Save the changes and push the file back to its location. When doing that, make sure to delete the files `cookies.sqlite-shm` and `cookies.sqlite-wal` in the data directory of Firefox. They are temporary files created when `cookies.sqlite`  is opened.

For a non-rooted device, you may consider pulling the data directory using `adb backup`. Extract the backup using [ABE](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor). Make the changes, pack the directory into a backup file and restore it in the device. I don't guarantee that restore would work.

There are some [addons here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/android/search/?q=cookie&appver=&platform=) which you may try and tell us if they work. They should work regardless of superuser access.

Comment: Thanks for posting all this although the only chance for me are the add-ons.

Answer (score 0):

I have version 50 beta and just used root with the rm command to remove the files. Next I created new empty ones with touch. It still works. 
The desktop version has an option to delete cookies on closing ff.